# how to debug helm secret status=failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I wonder how can I debug `status=failed` when using helm secret.

```
Name:         sh.helm.release.v1.dm-amr.v2
Namespace:    anga
Labels:       modifiedAt=1651288667
              name=dm-amr
              owner=helm
              status=failed
              version=2
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  helm.sh/release.v1

Data
====
release:  6596 bytes
```

Due to the failure, k8s secrets cannot be created, therefore the whole `helmfile sync` failed.

I had tried `helmfile template`, and it worked fine, which indicates that secrets decryption is not a problem. What could be the reasons leading to `status=failed`?

Comment: You're looking at Helm's internal state; this Secret isn't directly derived from anything in your chart and there's no particular reason to try to decode it.  What's the actual problem you're trying to debug?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause.
I did not have any corresponding secret yaml file in the original helm chart.